# Characterisation of a complete first-order theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $T$ be a set of formulas of a first-order language $L$. Show that $T$ is complete if and only if there is no sentence $A$ of $L$ such that both $T \cup \{ A \}$ and $T\cup \{\neg A\}$ are consistent.

I feel like the answer is staring me in the face and yet I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: Well, what is your definition of a complete theory?

Comment: A set of formulas (the theory) that proves, for every formula A of the language, either A or it's negation.

Comment: So if that's your position, how can both $T\cup A$ and $T\cup\lnot A$ both be consistent?

Comment: And what is your definition of a consistent theory?

Comment: one where at least one formula of the language is not a theorem of the theory (consistency)

Answer (score 0):

> $T$ be a complete theory iff either $T \cup \psi$ or $T \cup \neg\psi$ is inconsistent

**Proof ($\Rightarrow$)**: Let $T$ be a complete theory. Hence for every sentence $\phi$, either $T \vdash \phi$ or $T \vdash \neg \phi$. Now let $\psi$ be any sentence. We show that either $T \cup \psi$ or $T \cup \neg\psi$ is inconsistent. By our assumption of $T$ being a complete theory, it follows that either $T \vdash \psi$ or $T \vdash \neg \psi$ must be the case. If the former, then $T \cup \neg\psi$ is inconsistent. If the latter, $T \cup \psi$ is inconsistent.

This shows only that if $T$ be a complete theory then either $T \cup \psi$ or $T \cup \neg\psi$ is inconsistent. Now, can you complete the proof showing that the other direction ($\Leftarrow$) also holds?

Comment: thanks. And yeah I got the other direction. Let $A$ be an arbitrary formula
of $L$ and assume either $T \cup \{ A \}$ or $T\cup \{\neg A\}$  is
inconsistent. If the former then (using a lemma on consistency) $T$ proves
$\neg$$A$. If the latter $T$ proves $A$.

Comment: @Casey Exactly. Proofs tend to get a lot easier when we analyse their logical form and look carefully at the definitions. Congratulations! :)